# How to apply MellowMax Softmax operator

Tags: notation

I'm currently reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.05628) 'An alternative Softmax Operator for Deep Reinforcement Learning' but not having a solid foundation in maths notation is making it quite difficult.

I attempted applying the softmax operator ([MellowMax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5GrQ.png)) to the matrix [1, 2, 3, 4] with w = 2 but I'm going wrong somewhere along the way. I'd imagine it would be fairly straightforward for someone with a degree in maths but my lack of knowledge in this area is making it difficult. I know from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVBQGKMX974) 'An Alternative Softmax Operator for Reinforcement Learning' that I should be getting 3.3794 with matrix [1, 2, 3, 4] and w = 2 but I'm getting 1.46. My workings are below. I think I'm just applying the above MellowMax equation incorrectly due to my lack of knowledge of maths notation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[Applying MellowMax attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg58W.jpg)

Comment: I think by $\log$ they mean $\log$ in base $e$ but you calculate it in base 10!!! $\log_{10}(3446.3739)/2=1.467651206$ and $\log_{e}(3446.3739)/2=3.379391788$

Comment: See last equation before section 5.2 of article it is $log_e$.

Comment: @BryanCarty Welcome to Math SE. Basically the same question, by the unregistered user [Bryan Carty](https://mathoverflow.net/users/499892/bryan-carty), so I assume it's you, was posted about an hour ago on MathOverflow at [How to Apply MellowMax Softmax Operator](https://mathoverflow.net/q/441418). Note that cross-posting is generally frowned upon, at least if it's done within less than a week or so of the original post. Nonetheless, since the MathOverflow question is now closed, so it very likely won't be answered, I suggest you just delete that other question.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the help :)